# Can I Start/Stop a job based on a parameter?

Tags: scheduled-job, cron

I have a Cron job that runs every minute:

```
Datetime sysTime = System.now().addMinutes(1);
String cronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
System.schedule('Repeater Upload Contracts', cronExpression, new Repeater_Scheduler_Upload_Contract());
```

I now have a requirement, to be able to start/stop it multiple times, and also for Non admins.

Is it possible via some parameter?

- Custom Label?
- Custom Setting?
- Custom Object and a PB+Flow?

My first thought was a custom label of: Active/Inactive - But I don't see a way to move forward with this.

I can't capture the label-value change, thus can't trigger anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Even a non-admin won't be able to easily use a Custom Label, for example, because you need Customize Application to deploy Custom Labels, so that won't work for your purpose. I think you're overthinking this. Just write a Visualforce page or Lightning Component, and have it call System.scheduleJob or System.abortJob to start/stop the job, assuming you don't care which user "owns" the job, or have the Schedulable class check a Custom Setting and either execute the main logic or not, then keep scheduling itself:

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
  if(shouldJobRun()) {
    doJob();
  }
  scheduleForNextMinute();
}
```

This way, an admin only needs to schedule it once, and any user can decide to turn it on or off if they have permission to the UI that allows this.

Assuming you use a Custom Setting, you can just:

```
static Boolean shouldRunJob() {
  return true == Toggle_Settings__c.get('ShouldJobXRun')?.Enabled__c;
}
```

Where Toggle_Settings__c is just a Custom Setting that contains a bunch of potential Boolean flags, and Enabled__c is a checkbox. We can even use the Safe Navigation Operator to avoid an if statement here.